# Angular4 IIS Virtual Directory Deployment - main.bundle.js 404 Not Found

Tags: visual-studio, angular

I already installed URL rewrite and made a web.config file for my angular application. But when I browse the site from my localhost the below error appears:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are getting an error for the `/langs/us.json` file, have you set up your `--base-href` or `--deploy-url` so that those assets are being served from the correct virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: @0mpurdy Yes. This is my base-href:   <base href="./">, my virtual directory resides inside Default Website in IIS. And this is my web.config rewrite value <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />.

Comment: Are you running the website at a virtual directory eg: `localhost/virtual-directory/`

Comment: @0mpurdy yes I am.

Comment: Try using the command `ng build --aot --prod --deploy-url "/virtual-directory/" --base-href "/virtual-directory/"`

Comment: Same error us.json, but now in polyfill.